# Explain naming precedence again? I'm kind of in a bind

Tags: scala

I saw a test case for name binding that made me go huh? so here is a recap of the simple rule.  I'm sure this has been reviewed in many blog posts and SO questions.

The test case, object `Top`, ensures that `PrimaryKey` is ambiguous.

"Huh?" I thought imports were a "lower priority." Why shouldn't it compile?

Why is it only a problem inside curly braces (see `X2`)?

```
package imps

object X {
  object Y {
    val Z = 7
  }
  object A {
    val Z = 9
    import Y.Z
    println(Z)
  }
}

object X2 {
  object Y {
    val Z = 7
  }
  object A {
    val Z = 9
    locally {
      import Y.Z
      println(Z)
    }
  }
}

object Top {
  object ColumnOption {
    object PrimaryKey
  }

  class A {
    def PrimaryKey: Any = ???

    {
      import ColumnOption._

      (null: Any) match { case PrimaryKey => }

      PrimaryKey // was already ambigious in 2.10.3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for "being in a *bind*" with name binding precedence :D.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple illustration at the beginning of Chapter 2 of the spec.  For some reason I had not internalized it, so here it is, externalized.

The test case, object `Top`, ensures that `PrimaryKey` is ambiguous.

I thought imports were a "lower priority," so I tried `X`, which compiles.

But in a nested scope, see `X2`, the import becomes ambiguous.

The reason is that within a scope, see `X`, the local `Z` has higher precedence than the imported `Z`.

But in the nested scope, the `val Z` is no longer local to the scope, so it is "in scope" without being "local" to it.  Furthermore, the imported `Z` does not shadow it, as the spec says, because it has a lower precedence.  Hence the error about the ambiguous `Z`.